# How can I get cookies from Puppeteer chrome session C#?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, puppeteer-sharp, datascript

I need to get cookies of particular website from puppeteer chrome session and add these cookies to script.Here is code I am doing to get cookies form page:

```
page.GetCookiesAsync();
```

But it return:

> Id = 7315, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Other way I have tried:

```
page.Client.SendAsync("Network.getAllCookies");
```

Both methods not working for me.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution of the `GetCookiesAsync` task needs to be awaited, like this:

```
private async Task YourMethod()
{ 
    var result = await page.GetCookiesAsync();
}
```

You might need to change your callers for this.

Try to read about asynchronous programming in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

---

So what you are seeing with this:

> Id = 7315, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

is the async task not yet completed. `GetCookiesAsync` returns immediately. If you want to want to wait for the result, you should `await` it.

Comment: You mean like this page.Client.SendAsync("Network.getAllCookies").Wait();

Comment: I have tried this code:  page.Client.SendAsync("Network.getAllCookies").Wait();
                var ob = page.Client.SendAsync("Network.getAllCookies");

Comment: If you're doing it sync, you will need: `Result`

Comment: @Mobeen: try to read up into async/await and Tasks in C# ... it will help you get forward with these things ;-)

Comment: Can you remove the second example @Stefan? That could be problematic.

Comment: @hardkoded: sure, but it is the one that eventually helped OP.

Comment: @Mobeen: the solution offered (with `.Result`) is not really recommended since it can lead to problems. For it to work properly, use the links I provided. I will remove the example.